# Counting solutions of a cubic congruence using Gauss sums

Tags: number-theory, combinatorial-number-theory

In the introduction to André Weil's *Number of solutions of equations in finite fields* he mentions article 358 of Gauss' *Disquisitiones*. Can someone please show me the connection here:

How does the Gaussian sum of order $3$, for primes of the form $p = 3n+1$ determine the number of solutions for all congruence $ax^3 - by^3 = 1 \pmod p$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By ignoring a small subcase ($c = 0$ or $d = 0$), we can count the solutions for $cd \neq 0$ by the sum
$\displaystyle \sum_{\stackrel{c+d = 1}{c,d \neq 0}} \#\{x:ax^3 = c\} \times \#\{y: -by^3 = d\} ... (*)$.

**Expressing the term in this sum, using multiplicative characters:**

Now we look at $\{x: x^3 = u\}$ for some $u$, and we want to calculate its size. This can be interpreted as a sum of cubic characters: $\chi(u) + \chi^2(u) + \chi^3(u)$, where $\chi$ is a cubic character on $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. $\chi \neq 1$, but $\chi^3 = 1$. Now where does this interpretation come from?

1. If $x^3 = u$ has one solution, it has 3 because $p \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ tells us that 1 has 3 cube roots in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. On the character side, if $u$ is a cube of something, using $\chi^3 = 1$ w see that $\chi(u) + \chi^2(u) + \chi^3(u) = 3$.
2. If $x^3 = u$ has no solution, then notice that $\chi(u) \neq 1$. Then if we write $S = \chi(u) + \chi^2(u) + \chi^3(u)$, note that $\chi(u)S = \chi(u)$, which means $S = 0$.

So how does this interpretation in terms of characters help? Plug in the character sums in (*). We are going to have a lot of cross terms. These cross terms can be splitted into sums of [Jacobi sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_sum), which are closely related to Gauss sums. (See [Koblitz' Introduction to Elliptic Curves and Modular forms Section 2.2](http://books.google.com/books?id=99v9XcOjhO4C&lpg=PA58&dq=Koblitz%27%20Introduction%20to%20Elliptic%20Curves%20and%20Modular%20forms%20Section%202.2&pg=PA56#v=onepage&q&f=false), or [Ireland and Rosen's A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=jhAXHuP2y04C&lpg=PP1&dq=ireland%20and%20rosen&pg=PA92#v=onepage&q&f=false))

**The situation here:**

In our case,
$(*) = \sum_{c+d = 1, c,d \neq 0} \left(1 + \chi(c/a) + \chi^2(c/a)\right)\left(1 + \chi(-d/b) + \chi^2(-d/b)\right)$. 
There are three types of sum in the expansion. I would do one in each type to show you how it feels like.

1. $\displaystyle \sum_{c+d = 1, c,d \neq 0} 1 = p-2$, since $c$ can't be 0 or 1 and can be everything else.
2. $\displaystyle \sum_{c+d = 1, c,d \neq 0} \chi(c/a) = -\chi(1/a)$. To show this, note that for a nontrivial character $\chi$, $\displaystyle \sum_{u \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}} \chi(u) = 0$, by an argument similar to what we showed in step 2 in the last block.
3. $\displaystyle \sum_{c+d = 1, c,d \neq 0} \chi(c/a) \psi (-d/b)$, where $\psi = \chi$ or $\chi^2$. This is the one we need Jacobi sums $\displaystyle J(\chi, \psi) = \sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}} \chi(x)\psi(1-x)$. Note that

$\displaystyle \sum_{c+d = 1, c,d \neq 0} \chi(c/a) \psi (-d/b) = \chi(1/a)\psi(-1/b) J(\chi, \psi)$

and that if you check out the books I mentioned before, $J$ can be expressed by Gauss sums of $\chi$ or $\chi^2$.

**Summary:**

So after all these work, we can find $\displaystyle \sum_{\stackrel{c+d = 1}{c,d \neq 0}} \#\{x:ax^3 = c\} \times \#\{y: -by^3 = d\} $ in terms of Gauss sums. There remains the case $c = 0$ or $d = 0$, which is easy to do directly. Sum them up, and you get the answer. The two books I mentioned both have examples of these types, so you may want to read them.